# Hiding all instances of 2 divs depending on contents of a string

Tags: javascript, html

I have a custom Wordpress blog post page that is showing personnel profile cards, 12 people at a time. Sometimes, people have a Twitter handle, others not. When the value entered in the backend for their handle is "none", both the title and the Twitter field should be hidden, for ALL people on the same screen (again, paginating through 12 people at a time). Otherwise, it should show both.

```
<p>Sample text</p>
<div class="twitter-handle-title">
  <p>Twitter Handle:</p>
</div>
<div class="twitter-handle-text">
  <p>@twitter</p>
</div>


<p>Sample text.</p>
<div class="twitter-handle-title">
  <p>Twitter Handle:</p>
</div>
<div class="twitter-handle-text">
   <p>None</p>
</div>
```

This is the javascript I was trying to use,  but doesn't work:

```
let txt = document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-handle-text").innerText;
if (txt == "None") {
    document.getElementsByClassName('twitter-handle-title').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByClassName('twitter-handle-text').style.display = "none";
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `txt` instead of the value you expect?

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an "array-like` nodelist. It doesn't have `style` or `innerText` properties. You need to iterate over each element in the list and apply the style to them instead.

Comment: If the value within the <p></p> says "None", then both the classes should be hidden. Otherwise, it will show a twitter handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` of all of the targeted elements.

To apply your intended logic to each profile card you will need to iterate over each one and run your checks and style updates on *each* iteration.

To make this easier, I'd suggest adding a wrapper to each card element in order to encapsulate your logic. Something like this:

```
<div class="profile-card">
  <p>Sample text.</p>
  <div class="twitter-handle-title">
    <p>Twitter Handle:</p>
  </div>
  <div class="twitter-handle-text">
    <p>None</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can select all of the card wrappers using a document interface such as `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll`.

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.profile-card');
```

Once we have a collection of all of the `profile-card` elements, we can loop over each wrapping element using the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) array method. Now that we are encapsulated within each card we can apply your logic.

For the inner selectors I'd recommend using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) as we only need to select a single element by class name rather than a collection.

```
cards.forEach((card) => {
  if (card.querySelector('.twitter-handle-text').innerText === 'None') {
    card.querySelector('.twitter-handle-title').style.display = 'none';
    card.querySelector('.twitter-handle-text').style.display = 'none';
  }
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: May I ask a follow up question? If the text doesn't say "none", but instead has a Twitter handle, written as "@whatever" (no quotes), how would one replace this text into an actual URL like "https://twitter.com/whatever" ?

Comment: Grab the text using something like `innerText`, then create an anchor element ([createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)), concatenate the base twitter url with the handle text you previously extracted and set this as the anchor href, then insert the newly created anchor element into your page wherever you need it.